# Cannot center image gallery inside main div

Tags: html, css, image, gallery

I am gettin crazy trying to center this image gallery within the main div; it seems to be fine but when using screen resolution of 1350px you can actually see that there is an undesired margin to the right that creates a blank column on the right of the page and force display a horizontal scrollbar on the browser... I tried all but cannot make it work :( any idea?

You can see at http://www.bahelitours.com/es/helis-test

Comment: It's because of the `clip: rect()` you're applying to those images. If you get rid of that and just apply `height: 400px; width: 400px;` to the images, then everything is contained as it should be. `clip` basically treates the clipped portion of the image as `visibility: hidden;` leaving the layout of the clipped area on the page.

Comment: Provide a https://plnkr.co/ or https://jsfiddle.net/ sample plz